# BEA weblogic datasource with multiple network adapter

Tags: database, oracle, unix, weblogic

There are multiple nic in the linux machine where oracle BEA is installed. As in the listenAddress to listen the admin or manage server at specific address, Is it possible for the bea weblogic datasource adapter to use specific address/interface for the db transaction?

Or is it is just good enough to use iptables to forward the db client to server transaction at specific  network interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a hostname that map to the oracle server at at the hostfile.

Answer (score 0):

If you need WLS to use only 1 of the multiple nic then configure an explicit listen address to one of the nic's.

Comment: Sirdar that's what I mentioned in the question...  Those are for management console listening....  what I am looking for is the db transaction interface configuration